# Appium session not starting in Windows

Tags: windows, appium, appium-android

I am facing below problem while starting a new session in appium. It was working fine before one day.

The best matching driver provider `org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver` can't create a new driver instance for Capabilities

> [{app=C:\Users\user\Desktop\aapium\WhatsApp.apk, newCommandTimeout=0,
>   platformVersion=6.0.1, platformName=Android,
>   connectHardwareKeyboard=true, deviceName=GalaxyA5}] Build info:
>   version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19
>   -0700' System info: host: 'xxxxxxx', ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version:
>   '11.0.5' Driver info: driver.version: unknown